# How to add/delete element from hash which is being used by thread

Tags: ruby

I am trying to add the element in hash which is being use by a thread, it is throwing below error
linkEvent': can't add a new key into hash during iteration (RuntimeError)

```
@serverDown = Hash.new
def eventMessage(message)

  @server_thread = Thread.new do
        until @serverDown.empty?
          @serverDown.each do |key, value|
              puts "#{key}"
              sleep 3
        end
          Thread.stop if @serverDown.empty?
      end
    end
  end

  if message.include?("down")
    state = message.split.last
    puts "Adding #{state} to hash"
    @serverDown[state] = Time.now.to_i
    @server_thread.wakeup unless @server_thread.alive?
  end
end

@queue = Queue.new
@queue << "server is down"
@queue << "server is down"
@queue << "server is down"
@queue << "server is up"
@equeue << "unreachable"

until @queue.empty?
  event = @queue.pop
  if event.include?("down") || event.include?("up")
    eventMessage(event)
    sleep 3
    next
  end
  puts "#{event}"
end
```

I want to lock the thread and add the element to hash later resume the thread.

Comment: You need a mutex and a conditional variable around `@serverDown.each` _and_ around `@serverDown[state] = ...`.

Comment: I tried but did't get success, if you don't mind can you please give some code example to use mutex as per my requirement

Comment: There's an example [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html). Btw, are you sure the `Thread.new` call should go inside the `eventMessage` function? You are launching a new listener thread each time the function is called.

Comment: I want, thread should run until the hash map has element, do you have any suggestion for it? my intention is to "server is down" event should handle by a thread